# NSInvocation and by reference parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using `NSInvocation` to call a method, which I don't know at compile time.

It works fine, by I didn't find how to pass an argument of type `NSError**`.

Just as an example, suppose I want to call the method `-(BOOL)removeItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error` from `NSFileManager`.

The code would look something like this:

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
SEL selector = @selector(removeItemAtPath:error:);
NSMethodSignature *signature = [manager methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
[invocation setTarget:manager];
[invocation retainArguments];
[invocation setSelector:selector];

NSString *path = ...;
[invocation setArgument:&path atIndex:2];
NSError *error = ...;
[invocation setArgument:&error atIndex:3];    // Passing NSError*, not NSError**
```

This is a simplified example. I avoided adding the error-checking code to make it easier to read.

Also, I don't know the type of the arguments at compile time, I just get the parameters as `id`.

This is what I tried, but didn't work

```
id argument = ...
NSUInteger index = ...
const char *argType = [signature getArgumentTypeAtIndex:index];
if (strcmp(argType, "^@") == 0) {
    // object pointer
    id __strong *argumentPointer = &argument;
    [invocation setArgument:&argumentPointer atIndex:index];
}
else {
    [invocation setArgument:&argument atIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I'd try a different approach. There is very little chance that you can get an NSError* __autoreleasing* parameter handled correctly.

Comment: @gnasher729, what would you recommend?

Comment: I'd probably try to use a block, or a switch statement handling multiple functions etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

The *by reference* parameter needed to be declared as `__autoreleasing`

This is the code that is working now:

```
id __autoreleasing argument = ...
NSUInteger index = ...
const char *argType = [signature getArgumentTypeAtIndex:index];
if (strcmp(argType, "^@") == 0) {
    // object pointer
    NSObject * __autoreleasing *argumentPointer = &argument;
    [invocation setArgument:&argumentPointer atIndex:index];
}
else {
    [invocation setArgument:&argument atIndex:index];
}
```